# Html canvas image upload through ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ocr, tesseract

A year ago I tried to upload a canvas picture through ajax to my server for OCR purpose, main issues were the DPI of the picture which was too low resulting in an error with TesseractOCR and the fact that it had to be sent as a base64 string which would result in browser crash/freeze when using the targeted devices which are mobile phones.

My objective is to create an **html** page that live-scans using the phone's camera and if a specific pattern of number is found, return a true result and fill a part of a present form (like the Amazon android app that scans your credit card and fills the input).

Is there a way to achieve this without a page reload and through ajax ? I am aware that a traditional file upload would allow the image to be fully sent and better for OCR instead of a low sized dpi canvas drawn.